# what is the difference of Pretty Good Privacy and Gnu Privacy Guard

Tags: pgp

i want to know about the difference. of this two. because as far as i know  many cryptocurrency users.  use this for  more secure  transactions specially when the amount is huge.. to prevent identity while having a discussion about the transaction.

Comment: This isn't really directly related to cryptocurrency.  They're both tools used for signing or encrypting arbitrary data.  PGP came first, GPG was a clone released under a GPL license.

Comment: so no difference?. the same?. no dis advantages and advantages?. only the license?

Comment: Your question is like asking what the difference between a web browser and Chrome is. GPG is an implementation of the PGP protocol. For the rest, this question is offtopic here as it's unrelated to cryptocurrencies.

Comment: This question is unrelated to cryptocurrencies.

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13111/if-pgp-and-gpg-both-follow-the-openpgp-standard-are-they-100-compatible-in-all

Answer (score 3):

Both PGP and GPG are software implementations of the OpenPGP protocol. Typically when people say "PGP" they refer to the OpenPGP protocol.

OpenPGP itself specifies the formats for messages and keys. Both the PGP software and GPG are implementations which produce OpenPGP messages and keys.